# hook_form_alter() and hook_nodeapi() to alter fields and insert additional data on insert

Tags: 6, hooks

I have the code below, and I want to update the fields on my node using `hook_nodeapi()`. How do I set the fields on insert?

```
/*
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */

function feature_contact_form_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { 
  if ($form_id == 'contact_form_node_form') {
    $form['field_user_agent']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $form['field_ip_address']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $form['buttons']['submit']['#weight'] = 1;
  }
}

/*
 * Implements hook_nodeapi().   
 */
function feature_contact_form_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($node->type == 'contact_form') {
    if ($op == 'insert') {
      function getRealIpAddr() {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
          $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
          $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else {
          $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
      }

      $ipaddress = getRealIpAddr($ip);
      $node->field_user_agent = array($ipaddress);
      $node->field_ip_address = array($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: By fields do you mean CCK fields or (to use D7 speak) 'properties' of the node (e.g. uid, type, etc.)?

Comment: fields in my form are also properties in my node object depending on the context, no?

Comment: Sure, but any properties the node schema doesn't know about won't be persisted automatically. For example if you have `$form['test']` in your form, you'll be able to access it at `$node->test` in the insert op, but Drupal doesn't know to do anything with that data so it won't write it to the db or load it back up when the node is reloaded. I might've misunderstood what you mean though, sorry if that's the case

Comment: that is correct. you understood well. How do I persist the data across and insert it properly? Is hook_nodeapi what I need for this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments any extra fields you add to to a node form won't automatically be persisted to the database, the node module only takes care of the fields that it knows about.

Traditionally there are 2 options:

1. Use [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) instead and add fields to the node that way. Then you don't need to take care of data storage/loading yourself.
2. Add your own table for data storage using [`hook_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!install.php/function/hook_schema/6), making sure you have a column for `nid` (node id). Then in `hook_nodeapi()` use the `insert` and `update` ops to run a `db_query()` to insert/update the data in that table for the current node.

   Then you just need to load that data back from the DB on to the `$node` object in the `load` op of `hook_nodeapi()`. Your data will then be available at `$node->field_name` when you have a node object loaded with `node_load()`.

Comment: I already have added the fields using CCK. Fields: field_user_agent, field_ip_address already exist. I just set them as hidden on hook_form_alter.

Comment: I wasn't sure so I included it anyway, just ignore that bit of it's not relevant :)

Comment: I need to use the code in hook_nodeapi to capture the user_agent info and IP address but I still don't understand how to save that. Is the only option to use hook schemea and do the inserts manually?

Comment: I think we might be misunderstanding each other here...so `field_user_agent` and `field_ip_address` are already CCK fields? I was under the impression they weren't. If you want to manually set the value you can do so in the `presave` op of `hook_nodeapi()` (before the node data is actually saved) and set a value like `$node->field_user_agent[0]['value'] = $ua;`. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yeah I was having a brain freeze there. I was just about to post       $node->field_user_agent['0']['value'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
      $node->field_ip_address['0']['value'] = $ipaddress;